# Выбрать две таблицы по общему признаку и изменить поле на указанное значение

Tags: mysql, sql, веб-программирование, запрос, таблицы

Помогите с запросом, нужно вытянуть все товары из одной категории и затем у этих товаров массово изменить значение поля field_x на 1.

Есть две таблицы.

Таблица 1. "Товары" (product)

```
product_id | field_x     |
1          |    0        |
2          |    0        |
3          |    0        |
4          |    2        |
```

Таблица 2. "Категории" (category)

```
category_id | product_id
   1        |   1
   1        |   2
   2        |   3
   2        |   4
```

Пробовал вот такое написать:

SELECT * FROM `product`LEFT JOIN `category` ON `category`.`category_id` =`product`.`product_id`;

Что-то вытягивается, но изменить **field_x** из этой выборки не получается.

Comment: Правильно. Чтобы изменить значение, надо делать UPDATE

Comment: т.е. написать типа:
UPDATE  productvLEFT JOIN category ON category.category_id =product.product_id SET field_x = 1;
?